# How to fix navigator.share error "file size too large". Can I change max shared file size?

Tags: size, share

Web Share API (navigator.share) is working perfectly on a WAMP website that has thousands of JPG photos and dozens of MP4 videos. There is no problem for users sharing any of the JPG files or small MP4 video files (all location data is scrubbed using exiftool before sending a file). But when trying to share larger MP4 files, I get the error "Share too large". Can the max file size be changed? What is its default? What is imposing the size limit?

I have tried to find what component is imposing the file size limit and find a way to increase it. Even if the attachment file size for Gmail, for example, is over its limit, the email server provides the option of using a cloud-based service for sending the huge file.

I have never implemented the Web Share API before, so I expect my question may prove to be embarrassing.